# Hide and show object on Tkinter.Text

Tags: python, tkinter

I use Tkinter.Text widget for show large number of different subwidget objects.
I use command Text.window_create for show object.
If I used pack, grid or place geometry manager than I could use _forget method for hide object.
But in Text widget I can only show and can't hide.
If I delete subwidget then I can't show this subwidget again with error

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name
```

I found the only way is to recreate objects. But it is long and memory leaks occur.

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
tx = Text(root)
tx.pack() 
bt = Button(tx,text=u'TEST')
tx.window_create(END,window=bt) 
# ... How to hide ?
# ... How to show ?
root.mainloop()
```

That's why I don't use a pack, grid or place geometry manager. Try this example,  resize the window (button wrap to next line).

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
tx = Text(root)
tx.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH) 
for i in range(100):
    bt = Button(tx,text=u'TEST %s' % i)
    tx.window_create(END,window=bt) 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why to complicate things? Text widgets are intended to manage text. Use some other appropriate widgets instead (like Canvas, for example)

Comment: In my case, the Text widget is convenient because the objects when you resize window wrap to the next line.
Standard geometry managers do not give me that option.

Comment: You can reproduce the same behavior with Canvas. Use, for example, the `grid()` layout manager and set it like this: `canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)` and `canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)` (it really does the job)

Comment: You can read the section [**Handling resize**](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) for a detailed and clear explanation.

Comment: I have added an example explaining why I use Text and window_create.

Comment: You can put widgets like this in a `Text` widget. As @BillBEGUERADJ said they're really intended just for text management. If you're wanting to dynamically place widgets and hide / unhide them you could simplify things greatly by just using a frame etc and pack/ grid forget. As you noted the only way to really do this is deletion and recreation.

Comment: I found a workaround.
If previously to keep values text, image and bd attributes.
It is possible to almost hide objects 


`for el in map(tx.nametowidget,tx.window_names()): el['text']=''; el['image']=''; el['bd']=0`

Comment: I believe Texts treat widget windows as 'characters'.  This is why they line up, more with instertions and deletions, and can be wrapped, just like normal characters.  If you keep a reference to each widget you wrap (unlike in the for loop), you can create a new window wrapper without having to recreate the widget itself.

Comment: Dear @terry-jan-reedy. If I remove the widget from Text, I can't add it to the Text again. This is the problem.

Comment: After some more experiments, it appears that `window_create` grabs 'ownership' of the widget passed.  One cannot use the widget in another `window_create` call, even before the first one is deleted.  There are two ways to provide the widget: `widget=<tkwidget>` as you did (the only way I have ever tried), and `create=<widget_function>`.  In the latter case, the function is called with no args to create the widget.  In this latter case, I expect the widget to be belong to the window and be destroyed with it.  It seems the same is true of the other method.  The Python wrapper becomes useless.

Comment: Terry-Jan-Reedy, I don't understand what you propose to do. Can you give an example.